# Configuring Cygwin for ConEmu with different start directory

Tags: windows, path, cygwin, 64-bit, conemu

I am using ConEmu 64bit with Cygwin 64bit on a Windows 7 machine.

I don't want to set the working directory for cygwin in my .bashrc, as I like to setup more than one Task for Cygwin with different path parameters.

I set up the "home directory" in the task parameters:

```
\dir "D:\Downloads\Programming\Selenium\"
```

and added this line in the commands window:

```
C:\cygwin64\Cygwin.bat --login -i
```

Nevertheless Cygwin does not start in the "cygwinized" version of the given directory (/cygdrive/d/Downloads/Programming/Selenium) but in "normal" home directory of my user (~).

I only found howto's on how to add a new path in bashrc. Maybe one of you can enlighten me.

Answer (score 5):

First of all, have you look at **contents** of your C:\cygwin64\Cygwin.bat? Why not?

```
@echo off
C:
chdir C:\cygwin64\bin
bash --login -i
```

Obviously, `Cygwin.bat` will never open bash in your desired dir.

---

Also, Cygwin ignores user defined startup directory! That is because cygwin always do `cd "${HOME}"` from `/etc/profile` script.

But, for example, bash from [msysgit](http://code.google.com/p/msysgit/) works properly.

---

**Solution**

However, `/etc/profile` script checks for `CHERE_INVOKING` environment variable before `CD` doing. So, the proper command line for starting cygwin will be:

```
set CHERE_INVOKING=1 & c:\cygwin64\bin\sh.exe --login -i
```

---

Another workarounds you may find in the project [wiki page](https://code.google.com/p/conemu-maximus5/wiki/CygwinWorkDir).

Comment: I don't think that it's bug of bash. If you execute bash with parameter "-l" or "--login", it's executed as **login shell**. That means it processes "profile" files and changes working directory to the user's home directory defined in "/etc/passwd".

If you execute bash without parameter "-l" or "--login", it's executed in normal mode, doesn't process "profile" files and preserves current working directory.

That's exactly the same as it works in Linux.

Comment: Proper solution and description added

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar demand (opening a new Cygwin-Tab in the folder currently viewed in explorer via the context menu) and found the following solution:

As stated by Maximus the Cygwin-Bash is usually opened by C:\cygwin64\Cygwin.bat which includes the login process. My approach was to change the working directory through the login.

***.bash_profile:***

```
if [ -f "${HOME}/startup.sh" ] ; then
  source "${HOME}/startup.sh"
fi
```

***startup.sh***

```
cdc "D:\Downloads\Programming\Selenium\"
#cdc is a custom function, see .bashrc
```

***.bashrc***

```
cdc()
{
   # converts a double-quoted windows-path and changes directory to it
   p=$(cygpath -u "$1")
   cd "$p"
}
```

The login progress thus changes the path of you bash to the one you've set in startup.sh. You might of course just type a Cygwin-compatible path in startup.sh without using the custom-function of .bashrc. It's still quite useful, especially if you want to want to use a dynamic startup.sh.

**More Dynamic-approach:**

Create a Cygwin.bat in C:\opt\ConEmu\ConEmu with the following content:

***Cygwin.bat***

```
@echo off

C:
echo cdc %1 > C:\opt\cygwin64\home\%USERNAME%\startup.sh 

:: Your ConEmu-Task-definition here
C:\opt\ConEmu\ConEmu64.exe /Single /cmd {Cygwin}
```

This one writes a cdc-command followed by the path you provide into your startup.sh and starts an new instance of the ConEmu-Task *Cygwin*. The task itself does not do anything but starting an instance of Cygwin in my configuration:

***ConEmu Task {Cygwin}***

```
"C:\opt\cygwin64\Cygwin.bat"
```

I invocate the Cygwin.bat through the context-menu of the explorer. Another way would be to make a Windows-Shortcut pointing to Cygwin.bat with you path appended.